# Как подключиться к Postgres Golang ORM: XORM

Tags: база-данных, postgresql, golang

Подключаюсь к БД следующим образом

```
// DB Config
package config
var Db map[string] string = map[string] string{
"DbType": "postgres",
"Host": "localhost",
"Port": "5432",
"User": "postgres",
"Password": "qazwsx1q",
"Dbname": "torgai",
}
//DB Connect
package db

import (
    "../config"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/go-xorm/core"
    "github.com/go-xorm/xorm"
    "log"
)
var engine *xorm.Engine
var c = config.Db

func init()  {
    var err error
    engine, err = Connect()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Fail to create engine: %v", err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n",engine)
    return
}

func Connect()(engine *xorm.Engine, err error) {
    tbMapper := core.NewPrefixMapper(core.SnakeMapper{}, "")
    psqlInfo :=fmt.Sprintf("host=%s port=%s user=%s "+
        "password=%s dbname=%s sslmode=disable",
        c["Host"], c["Port"], c["User"], c["Password"], c["Dbname"])
    engine, err = xorm.NewEngine(c["DbType"], psqlInfo)
    //engine.ShowSQL()
    engine.SetTableMapper(tbMapper)
    engine.SetColumnMapper(core.SnakeMapper{})
    return
}
```

В процессе коннекта никаких ошибок не выдаёт.
но когда вывожу соединение (engine), список таблиц пуст

```
&{db:0xc000214940 dialect:0xc00012bb30 ColumnMapper:{} TableMapper:{Mapper:{} Prefix:} TagIdentifier:xorm Tables:map[] mutex:0xc000291680 Cacher:<nil> showSQL:false showExecTime:false logger:0xc0002e0540 TZLocation:Local DatabaseTZ:Local disableGlobalCache:false tagH
andlers:map[VARBINARY:0x9919b0 MEDIUMTEXT:0x9919b0 TINYINT:0x9919b0 SERIAL:0x9919b0 TIMESTAMP:0x9919b0 CLOB:0x9919b0 REAL:0x9919b0 PK:0x9913e0 SYSNAME:0x9919b0 VERSION:0x9915b0 BOOL:0x9919b0 INT:0x9919b0 NTEXT:0x9919b0 TINYTEXT:0x9919b0 INTEGER:0x9919b0 LONGTEXT:0x99
19b0 NOTNULL:0x9914a0 UNIQUE:0x991860 CREATED:0x991590 UNIQUEIDENTIFIER:0x9919b0 BIGSERIAL:0x9919b0 NUMERIC:0x9919b0 JSONB:0x9919b0 DOUBLE:0x9919b0 DECIMAL:0x9919b0 AUTOINCR:0x9914c0 DELETED:0x9917b0 INDEX:0x9917d0 SMALLINT:0x9919b0 TIMESTAMPZ:0x9919b0 UTC:0x991630 B
INARY:0x9919b0 BLOB:0x9919b0 CHAR:0x9919b0 NULL:0x991410 TINYBLOB:0x9919b0 JSON:0x9919b0 TEXT:0x9919b0 ENUM:0x9919b0 UUID:0x9919b0 TIME:0x9919b0 ->:0x9913c0 CACHE:0x9922b0 BIT:0x9919b0 FLOAT:0x9919b0 MEDIUMBLOB:0x9919b0 <-:0x9913a0 DEFAULT:0x9914e0 VARCHAR:0x9919b0 N
VARCHAR:0x9919b0 DATE:0x9919b0 UPDATED:0x991790 SET:0x9919b0 LONGBLOB:0x9919b0 BYTEA:0x9919b0 NOT:0x991390 NOCACHE:0x9922e0 DATETIME:0x9919b0 BIGINT:0x9919b0 LOCAL:0x9916a0 COMMENT:0x9918f0 MEDIUMINT:0x9919b0] engineGroup:<nil> cachers:map[] cacherLock:{w:{state:0 se
ma:0} writerSem:0 readerSem:0 readerCount:0 readerWait:0}}/n0x9ae2f0
```

При подключении БД с через PgAdmin все таблицы видны

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы получить список таблиц сущствует специальный метод `DBMetas()`.

```
tables, err := engine.DBMetas()
fmt.Printf("Error: %v\nTables: %v", err, tables)
```